# Screen filter for colorblind

Tags: windows, display, color, accessibility

Is there a software that could help the colorblind by either filtering certain colors from the (computer) screen or modifying them in such a way as to make them more visible or distinguishable?

I found this related tool which is amazing: [Visolve](http://www.ryobi-sol.co.jp/visolve/en/download/) (more such tools: [15-tools-color-blindness](http://www.color-blindness.com/2008/12/23/15-tools-color-blindness/)), but it requires you to capture a certain part of your screen and go through the options.

Is there a tool that lets you do this **for the entire screen at the simple click of a button (main requirement)**?

[image: Tool showing the 'Transform' menu with an option 'Red filter']

As for what color filter it actually applies, either one of them is fine (red/blue/green filter) as long as it assists in the distinguishing the colors better.

Should work on Windows 8.

Comment: i have this problem too!!! i am slightly colourblind

Answer (score 2):

[Visolve Toolbar](http://www.ryobi-sol.co.jp/visolve/windows/en/toolbar.html)  claims:

> Visolve is the software that transforms colors of the computer display into the discriminable colors for various people including people with color vision deficiency, commonly called color blindness. In addition to distinguishing colors and finding a specific color, it aims to help people with color blindness:
>
>     - to guess a normal color, and
>     - to feel the color gradations in natural scenery etc. by their visual information.
>  
>
> Visolve can execute the following three types of color transformation, filtering, and hatching:
>
>     Red-Green transform -- transforms redder colors to brighter, and greener colors to darker,
>     Blue-Yellow transform -- transforms bluer colors to brighter, and yellower colors to darker,
>     Saturation increase -- increases the saturation of all colors,
>     Filtering -- darkens all colors other than the specified color, and
>     Hatching -- draws different hatch patterns depending on color. 
>
> When people with color blindness apply, for example, Red-Green transform, if they keep the above transformation rule in mind and see color changes, they could guess a normal color. Moreover, Red-Green transform reflects the degree of color saturation into its brightness regularly. So they could know not only the difference between red and green but also the difference between two reds, i.e., the degrees of red.

It [lets you play with images](http://www.ryobi-sol.co.jp/visolve/en/tryonweb.html) to see the effects.
It's available for Windows and Mac OS X, and is free for personal and non-commercial use.

By using Visolve Toolbar, you can apply color filter to the entire screen with just button click without the capture operation.
The toolbar will appear by selecting "Visolve" in "Toolbars" in the taskbar context menu.

Moreover, the toolbar appears at the Internet Explorer by selecting "Visolve" in "Toolbars" in the view menu. You can apply color filter to the whole Explorer's window area without the capture operation.

Comment: I have edited your answer because it did not meet site standards. Next time please put some more effort into it, or, if you don't want to, write this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your instructions.
But you should read the original question carefully again. The description of Visolve's general feature quoted from its web site doesn't solve it.
Because I couldn't add a comment to the original question for some reason, I wrote an answer again.

Answer (score 1):

[Vision](https://iristech.co/vision/) does this. It's software for real-time screen daltonization.

[image]

You can also customize the correction strength.

[image]

To calculate the values you need to use you can do this [color blindness test](https://iristech.co/test-vision).

[image]

Comment: When you are affiliated to the company (and I think you are) please mention this here and also mention price conditions and OS the product works on.

Comment: Hi Albert, sorry about this. I'm the creator of Vision. The software is free to use but has Pro version to customize the correction :)

Comment: Please provide this comment in your answer (preferably near the start).

Answer (score 1):

Windows already has native capability to do that since Windows 10 Build 16215 where there are some color filters for ease of access which can be toggled  by <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

> Windows 10 now includes color filters at the system level, including filters designed to make it easier for people with color blindness to differentiate between colors like red and green and to make it easier for people with light sensitivity to create and consume content. You can find these new filtering options under *Settings > Ease of Access > Color and High Contrast* (previously called High Contrast Settings).
>
> [Announcing Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 16215 for PC + Build 15222 for Mobile](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/06/08/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16215-pc-build-15222-mobile/#C1B2TQQ8YvwdEsjV.97)

[image: color filter settings]

The default filter is grayscale, which is why some people complain why [suddenly their Windows turns monochrome](https://superuser.com/a/1281353/241386) when [they accidentally press the shortcut](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/my-computer-spontaneously-turned-monochrome/fc0f7380-c333-480d-86c2-1eec77dddf6a)

And this is how it works on Windows 11

[image: Windows 11 color filter settings]