# Color blindness simulation

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, graphic-design, color

In order to check the perception of color choices, I'd like to be able to simulate color blindness for people with normal eyesight (me, basically).

My goal is to weaken / worsen / decrease the contrast in order to get a feeling how bad something (an advertisement, UI design etc.) is for a person with color vision deficiencies.

It should consider typical color blindness types that are medically accepted, like red-green blindness, blue weakness, blue blindness and monochromacy.

It's basically the opposite of what is requested in [Screen filter for colorblind](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19781/screen-filter-for-colorblind), where the goal is to improve the contrast for colorblind people.

Please suggest a gratis offline tool for Windows. Ideally it's not a Windows Store app, but something else to download and install.

I want it to work with the whole computer screen or a part of the screen. There should not be a need to make screenshots, save them, upload them or do image processing in any other way.

The application should not be specific to any program. I want to look at my Windows desktop application (Word, Paint, Photoshop), my Android emulator, any website in any browser, virtual machine etc. in almost real time (a single button click or hotkey is acceptable).

I do not need:

- a pure contrast analyzer like [Color Contrast Analyzer (CCA)](https://www.tpgi.com/color-contrast-checker/)

I have tried:

- [Color Oracle](https://colororacle.org/), butI can't run that outdated version of Java and I am not allowed to installed the paid version of Oracle's Java.

Comment: Is it online tool acceptable for you?

Comment: @RomeoNinov: no, sorry. It must work with our application. I know, I could make screenshots, upload them and look at the result. The process is just too slow. Also I might get in trouble if I upload screenshots of our unpublished application.

Comment: See my answer, I add there some offline tools you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some online tools which can emulate different types of colour blindness:
https://pilestone.com/pages/color-blindness-simulator-1

https://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/

In [Canva](https://www.canva.com/) online designer you have option to see image in the design as seen by colour blind.

If you are not fan of uploading images on some web sites you can use [Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/) browser to see particular page browser as colour blind.

You can use this add-ons for browser: [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lets-get-color-blind/bkdgdianpkfahpkmphgehigalpighjck?hl=en), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/let-s-get-color-blind/)

Comment: I've downloaded that Canary stuff. It looks like a browser and quacks like a browser - it is a browser? How does it help me simulate colorblindness?

Comment: Check this tweet how to do it: https://twitter.com/mathias/status/1237393102635012101?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1237393102635012101%7Ctwgr%5E36ed168805e21050436b556be3404dafe464cf66%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.makeuseof.com%2Ftag%2F3-easytouse-online-colorblindness-simulators%2F