# color blindness simulator

Tags: color

Can I simulate color blindess in real-time? The found some software but it doesn't do it real-time. I thought about turning down the saturation of a single color but I'm not sure if it has accurate results or how do to it. My monitor doesn't give an option to change single colors.
An example of what i dont need is color oracle, which takes a screenshot of the screen and applied a filter to it. I want it to be real time

Comment: did you see e.g. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87285/color-blindness-simulation and other questions of this site (just search for `color blindness`). Which software did you find?

Comment: nothing on that page is what im looking for

Comment: nor did vision ,

Comment: The question is why. Is it to check your own website?

Answer (score 2):

The Chrome Devtools have an option "Emulate reduced contrast" for common vision deficiences:

- No emulation.
- Blurred vision.
- Reduced contrast.
- Protanopia (no red). Low perception of red; confusion of greens, reds, and yellows.
- Deuteranopia (no green). Low perception of green; confusion of greens, reds, and yellows.
- Tritanopia (no blue). Low perception of blue; confusion of greens and blues.
- Achromatopsia (no color). Partial or total absence of color vision.

Read more here in the [DevTools documentation for Chrome 112](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-112/#reduced-contrast)

There is also a Youtube video demonstrating this but I cannot find it.

Comment: There is add-on for FIrefox too: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/87291/34845